# Calling Application Methods from a wx Frame Class

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, model-view-controller, project-organization

I'm starting out with wxPython and have been working my way through every tutorial and example I can get my hands on.  I've run into a slight problem, however, and it has to do with the wx.App versus the wx.Frame and which should contain specific methods.  Just about every example I've seen don't go much beyond layouts/sizers and event handling, none really tackle project organization of a wxPython project.

For example, I have a method that gets a list of folders.  The way most examples would deal with this would be to stick the method right in the frame class.  This method has the potential to be used in several other parts of the application, so it would make more sense to store it at the application class level.

How should I organize and call "universal" methods like these so that I don't clutter up my frame classes.

**UPDATE:**

To clarify, the "list of folders" was just an example, my actual method does a lot more work.  What I'm saying is I have code that isn't Frame-specific.  If I had this in the application class, what is the best way to call it from and event method in my frame.

I'm looking for actual project organization techniques, not programming fundamentals.

Comment: If you truly are on a learning adventure and you are not under a time crunch, then you might browse the source code of the Audacity application.  This is a very successful, non-basic, non-trivial app that happens to be open source *AND* uses wxWidgets. http://audacity.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classes that inherit from wxWidgets/wxPython data types should not implement any business logic. wxWidgets is a GUI library, so any subclasses of wxApp or wxFrame should remain focused on GUI, that is on displaying the interface and being responsive to user actions.

The code that does something useful should be separated from wx, as you can decide later to use it in some web or console application and you don't want to create wxApp object in such case. You can also decide later on to move some computations to separate 'worker threads', while your GUI will be the 'main thread' - responsive, and repainted properly during long lasting computations.

Last but not least - the classes that encapsulate your logic might tend to grow during projects lifetime. If they're mixed with your GUI classes they will grow faster, and finally they become so complex that you're almost unable to debug them...

While having them separated leads to clean code when you don't mix bugs in logic with bugs in GUI (refreshing/layout/progress bar etc.). Such approach has another nice feature - ability to split work among GUI-people and logic-people, which can do their work without constant conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark stated you should make a new class that handles things like this.

The ideal layout of code when using something like wxWidgets is the model view controller where the wxFrame class only has the code needed to display items and all the logic and business rules are handled by other class that interact with the wxFrame. This way you can change logic and business rules with out having to change your interface and change (or swap) your interface with out having to change your logic and business rules.

Answer (score 2):

I probably should have been a lot clearer from the start, but I found what I was looking for:

http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController/

Burried within the wxpython wiki, I found several simple, concrete examples of MVC projects.

Answer (score 0):

In a proper OOP design, this would be independent or part of a filesystem class - it wouldn't be part of the app or the frame.